# Localizing cocoa and iphone projects

Tags: iphone, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa, localization

I am in the process of localizing a mac application and wondering the approach I should take to localize the nib files. I used to localize the xib files by creating IBOutlets for every property in the xib such as labels. However I feel this is not the correct approach and should use the ibtool instead.

I have refered to this http://developer.casgrain.com/?p=94 as start point. But feels like creating IBoutlets is much easier and I can have the programmatically added strings and strings related to nibs at one place.

Can someone enlighten me about the downside of localizing xibs using IBOutlets?

Comment: All I can think of is that the layout of the label might be a bit off if the localization of the string take up more space, other which I don't see any problems. If you did localize all the `xib` files then any changes made to them will have to de made in all localized `xib`. Which could be a lot of work.

Comment: Yeah but I am skeptic to proceed this way since in no where in Apple documentation suggest this approach to link every ui element.

Comment: I've been doing it for some Apps, wich need to be multilingual. There isen't one way of doing things, if the Apple documentation does nto mention it does not mean that it's not a goed way. I no programmers that never ever use xib files they just code the UI which is also an option.